# Expected value of removing every ball once

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I thought of this question and I somehow I can't figure out an answer

Let there be a box with $n$ balls (which have numbers from $1$ to $n$ to that you can distinguish them). When we randomly pick a ball we write down its number and put the ball back into the box. We repeat this untill we have picked out every ball at least once, let $A$ be the amount of picks. What is the expected value of $A$?

I have thought about certainly interesting question quite a while but I just can't manage to find an elegant solution, maybe someone has an idea?

Edit: This problem is equivalent to the Coupon Collector's Problem, which means that the correct solution is $n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}$

Comment: This is a rewording of the [Coupon Collector's Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem)

Comment: To solve this problem beautifully you need to think it as a Markov chain, then you solve the expected value to change from state $n$ (after taking $n$ different numbers) to $n+1$ (i.e. the expected number of trials to take a new number when you already get $n$ numbers of $N$ different possible numbers). After you add all expectations (from $n=1$ to $n=N$) and violá!

Comment: [This is a very similar problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1639339/different-solution-of-probability-problem-from-textbook) (a bit more general) with the answer step by step.

Comment: Thanks for the phrase " Coupon Collector's Problem" that made it easier for me to find articles about this problem, I have successfull understood and solved it now :)